# Pie plate replacement

Tags: cassette

The pie plate / dork disk between the cassette and spokes on my bike cracked from age and I had to remove it. I'd like to get a replacement but I can't seem to find any online. Also, do I just need to get one based on the largest cog or is there anything else to consider?

Comment: Google "spoke guard" or "spoke protector" and you will find lots of options.  As to which to get, probably the main difference is how the unit mounts.  Some are made to tightly fit around the portion of the hub behind the cluster, while others have a large opening and fit by snapping onto the spokes.  The latter inevitably come loose and rattle.

Comment: Thanks, I kept searching for "pie plate". Yes the original had notches to fit behind the cassette.

Comment: Consider going without, and making sure your top limit screw is set right.  If the chain does go over the top, then immediately stop peddling, get off and fix it.

Comment: @Criggie: I'd go without (I keep the derailleur/limit screws trimmed myself), but it seems like cheap insurance against wrecking a wheel, having seen some of horrible damage I've seen. Also, if the chain goes over into the spokes, stopping the cranks will have no effect since the chain will still be moving relative to the wheel.

Comment: @kabZX Fair call - I did this once, and tried to get the chain back on by changing up and peddling.  This munched the bend of ~9 spokes, which started breaking over the next couple of weeks.   The plates are lightweight and close to the axle so why not.  Plus you can get reflective ones too.

Comment: @Criggie never knew about reflective ones. Thanks.

Comment: Like @Criggie said, a correctly tuned top limit screw is essential. Those disks fulfil no real need.

Answer (score 2):

A google search of Spoke Protector led to several suppliers. The size is based on largest cog. Most however are spec'd by overall dimension in inches not tooth count. There are two mounting styles I am familiar with. One type snaps onto the hub. There is a  difference between freehub and freewheel mounting. The other variety mounts by snapping onto the spokes. I can imagine that you need one that matches the spoke count of the wheel.